# Business intelligence software for visualizing data in form of gauges, charts, data tables, etc

Tags: data-visualization, saas, business-intelligence

I have researched and used many business intelligence based dashboards till date. Some of them include:

- [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/)
- [Slemma BI](https://slemma.com/)
- [Knowi BI](https://www.knowi.com/)
- [Klipfolio](https://www.klipfolio.com)
- [Sisense](https://www.sisense.com/)
- [Dundas BI](https://www.dundas.com/dundas-bi)

I understand that they are used to visualize data by integrating with various data sources. However, I find them lacking in various scenarios.

**All I want from a user interface software is to:**

- Visualize data in form of gauges, charts, data tables, etc.
- Integrate with database sources like MySQL and MongoDB
- Perform analytics in the back-end to generate analyzed results from datasets as cron jobs do.
- Send out email & SMS notifications to my users whenever, there is an error in incoming data.
- Authenticate my users depending on their company. I want to show them dashboards based on their user type.
- My datasource has to be refreshed every minute as data is incoming on my server per minute.
- Export more than 8 - 10 months of previous data from database whenever needed from UI.

**Which B.I based software is the most ideal for me?** Or do I build one from scratch with help of few developers?

Answer (score 2):

[Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com) provides an end to end [Dashboard solution](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) that can be used for Enterprise Dashboards and Analytics.

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard Platform]

- Visualize data in form of gauges, charts, data tables, etc.: Yes
- Integrate with database sources like MySQL and MongoDB: Yes
- Perform analytics in the back-end to generate analyzed results from datasets as cron jobs do: Can be done with the Syncfusion Data Integration Platform.
- Send out email & SMS notifications to my users whenever, there is an error in incoming data: Can be done with the Syncfusion Data Integration Platform.
- Authenticate my users depending on their company. I want to show them dashboards based on their user type: Yes.
- My datasource has to be refreshed every minute as data is incoming on my server per minute: Yes. Can be done with the Data Integration Platform.
- Export more than 8 - 10 months of previous data from database whenever needed from UI: Yes. Exporting is supported.

Syncfusion Dashboard Platform is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and licensing is relatively inexpensive otherwise.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Okay. Will Check and Let you know.